# Buttons are not responsive in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

So,i made a pause screen for my game in Unity i added buttons and stuff,everything was working fine
until i added the script for interacting with the buttons and i closed unity without testing then the other day i opened unity and boom the buttons were not interactive anymore i tried everything but could not do anything please help.Here's a Screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Did you tried to disable your actual canvas and create a new one with a new simple button ? This may show you if it's a problem with your canvas config, or the script you added to this GameObject, which may interact with the default behaviour.

Comment: I deleted the canvas made a new one with a button still unresponsive

Comment: so i started a new project and added a button and it works i dont know what the hell is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was something wrong with my script i was using the statement.

```
Cursor.LockState = CursorLockMode.locked;
```

which for some reason when i paused the game made my cursor unresponsive and not my buttons.I still haven't found a replacement.